# How can I map non-English Windows timezone names to Olsen names in Python?

Tags: python, winapi, timezone, locale, pywin32

If I call `win32timezone.TimeZoneInfo.local().timeZoneName`, it gives me the time zone name in the current locale (for example, on a Japanese machine, it returns `u"東京 (標準時)"`).

I would like to map this name to an Olsen database timezone name for use with `pytz`. [CLDR windowZones.xml](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) helps me to map English names, but can't handle the Japanese name.

How can I convert the name back to English (it should be `Tokyo Standard Time` in this case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict(win32timezone.TimeZoneInfo._get_indexed_time_zone_keys())` returns exactly the mapping I need from the current locale's name to the English name. The following code solves it:

```
  import win32timezone
  win32tz_name = win32timezone.TimeZoneInfo.local().timeZoneName
  win32timezone_to_en = dict(win32timezone.TimeZoneInfo._get_indexed_time_zone_keys())
  win32timezone_name_en = win32timezone_to_en.get(win32tz_name, win32tz_name)
  olsen_name = win32timezones.get(win32timezone_name_en, None)
  if not olsen_name:
      raise ValueError(u"Could not map win32 timezone name %s (English %s) to Olsen timezone name" % (win32tz_name, win32timezone_name_en))
  return pytz.timezone(olsen_name)
```

It would be nice if this was accessible in the `win32timezone.TimeZoneInfo` object, though, instead of having to call a private method.

Comment: It seems that GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation returns the registry key in `TimeZoneKeyName` which then can be used to map onto the English name if required. This seems a more stable way to approach this if possible, since on a multilingual system, the standard name gets returned in the current locale since XP SP3 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724253%28v=VS.85%29.aspx